# clear results from sublists

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a list of submenus. First, i'm getting info from a json file, and show the first results. Some of this results have 'x' quantity of sublevels. This is part of my code:

```
function getCategories(){
        $http.get('/app/json/categories.json')
        .then(function(data){
            $scope.categoriesList = data.data.categories;
            //console.log($scope.categoriesList);
        });
    }

    $scope.theSublevels = function(x){
        $scope.inside = x.sublevels;
        //console.log($scope.inside);
    }

    $scope.nextSublevel = function(y){
        $scope.inception = y.sublevels;
        //console.log($scope.inception);
    }
```

And on my html view:

```
<ul>
    <li class="listagem" ng-repeat="category in categoriesList">
      <a ng-click="theSublevels(category)">{{category.name}}</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="segunda-listagem" ng-repeat="next in inside">
            <a href="" ng-click="nextSublevel(next)">{{next.name}}</a>
              <ul>
                    <li class="sub-sublistagem" ng-repeat="other in inception">
                        <a href="">{{other.name}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Everything goes find except when the three levels are open, and change of father category `{{category.name}}`. The very first result change, but the sublevels stay the same until i click on the new first sublevel. What can i do to clear the next sublevels and show only the first sublevel?

I'm using AgularJs and Javascript.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul>
    <li class="listagem" ng-repeat="category in categoriesList">
      <a>{{category.name}}</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="segunda-listagem" ng-repeat="next in category.sublevels">
            <a href="">{{next.name}}</a>
              <ul>
                    <li class="sub-sublistagem" ng-repeat="other in next.sublevels">
                        <a href="">{{other.name}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You don't need to extract the child content on click, you can directly bind them. Try like above.